# CentOS Server not booting, can only ping it

Tags: centos

My server went down yesterday and i've just been trying to get it back online, I can ping it but i can't access SSH or HTTP etc.

I've rebooted it into rescue mode but i'm not 100% sure what i'm looking for.

What should i check for to see why its not booting properly ?

Answer (score 0):

It is booting when you are able to ping it. Its most likely the SSHd and the HTTP-Server (other services as well) don't start up automaticly. Type in `chkconfig sshd on` and reboot and try to connect via ssh again. Otherwise check log files and see if they tell more.

**edit**
Of furse you can't run `chkconfig` in rescue mode, my fault. Try this:
Mount the harddrive:
Example:
`mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`
Then run
`echo "/etc/init.d/sshd start" >> /mnt/etc/rc.local`
Reboot and try to connect. If it works set sshd to autostart using
`chkconfig sshd on`

Comment: I don't have access to chkconfig in rescue mode it says.

Comment: @exoon updated the answer for that.

Comment: I'm getting: sudo echo "/etc/init.d/sshd start" >> /mnt/etc/rc.local
-bash: /mnt/etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

Comment: As I said you need to mount the partition containing your operating system. You should get some info by using `lsblk` try to find your operationg system partition with help of the partition size etc. You need to mount this partition (in my case and example `/dev/sda1`) anywhere (Usually `/mnt` is used for that)

Comment: My main partition is 930G so i assume thats the OS so i did `mount /dev/sda2 /mnt` which didn't give any errors but then when i run `sudo echo "/etc/init.d/sshd start" >> /mnt/etc/rc.local` i get the error : 
`-bash: /mnt/etc/rc.local: Permission denied`

Comment: got it working by `sudo su` then running as root, tried rebooting and still can't login :(

Comment: Does your hoster offer a VNC-Console? If so try to boot normal and check if you can connect via VNC. Then check if the sshd is running. `sudo service sshd status`